# Minizinc IDE does not open anymore

Tags: minizinc

I am using Minizinc IDE (the latest version) on Windows 10. I have been using it for a time and everything was fine. All of a sudden, when I wanted to open Minizinc IDE, it shows that it is open in the taskbar, but the IDE windows does not appear! when I hover the mouse over the icon in the taskbar, it shows a white rectangle! I waited for an hour and no change, restarted my PC, uninstalled Minizinc software, and re-installed it again, but none of these have helped! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Their might be a problem with your search path. Or some dynamic link libararies (DLL) might be missing or hidden.

You could try a dependency checker like https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies to find and solve the problem.

Start at file "`...\MiniZinc\MiniZincIDE.exe`"

Here are the dependencies listed on my Windows 10 PC:

[image]